# Why does create from factory_girl throw error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails

When i don't use factory_girl

I can create objects in my rspec test as

```
 u = User.create(email: 'as@wewe.com', password: 'asdqweqweqe', admin: true, firstname: 'qwe', lastname: 'wer', grade: 5, section: 'w')
        expect(u.errors[:email]).to_not be_empty
   expect(u.errors[:role]).to_not be_empty
```

This way i can check for validation error i.e

```
   expect(u.errors[:role]).to_not be_empty
```

but if i use factory girl

```
  factory :user_no_role, class: User do

    email 'asd@we.com'
    password 'asasdasdasd'
    admin true
    firstname 'qwe'
    lastname 'wer'
    grade 5
    section 'w'

  end


it 'role should be present' do
        u = create(:user_no_role)
        expect(u.errors[:role]).to_not be_empty
  end
```

I get the following error

```
    User role should be present
     Failure/Error: u = create(:user_no_role)

     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Role can't be blank
```

does factory_girl create method throw error? if so how can i test for validation error with rspecs as done above? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create will throw validation exceptions, since you are trying to save them immediately.

If you would just build one, like:

```
u = User.new(...)

u.valid? 
=> false

u.errors # is not empty
```

This should apply to `FactoryGirl.build` too

```
it 'role should be present' do
  u = build(:user_no_role)
  expect(u.errors[:role]).to_not be_empty
end
```

BTW: `User.create` will not throw exceptions - but `User.create!` does.

See the [ActiveRecord docs of create!](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods/create%21) and [FactoryGirl docs of build](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#using-factories) for more infos.

Comment: u = build(:user_no_role)
  expect(u.errors[:role]).to_not be_empty is not working and i checked that u.errors[:role].length is 0 so looks like build will not populate errors array. if that is the case how can we verify the errors array?

Comment: What is `u.valid?`

Comment: validation works but the errors is not populated. is errors only populated on create?

Comment: interesting! This will fail u = build(:user_no_role)
        expect(u.errors[:role]).to_not be_empty
        expect(u).to_not be_valid   but this will succeed         u = build(:user_no_role)
        expect(u).to_not be_valid    
        expect(u.errors[:role]).to_not be_empty

Comment: looks like if valid is first called then it will populate errors array but if we first check the array it will be empty.